# Cannot connect to "local" (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have some database problems.

I have SQL Server Developer installed on my local machine. When I open SQL Server Management Studio and log in with windows authentication there is no problem. I have created a new database there and added a new user. The new user is owner of the database.

When I disconnect from my windows session and try to log in with the newly created user in SQL Server authentication mode I get the 'cannot connect to (local)'

Please help!

Comment: show your connection string, please - don't forget to replace the real password (if there's one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you enabled SQL Server authentication? (During installation and/or afterwards)

If not, connect using windows authentication, right-click on the server instance, go to properties and change auth mode...

[image]

Comment: Follow guide here to enable it, if it isn't : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem and i learned something new today :)

Comment: @Andy - Dont forget to accept the correct answer if it worked :-)

Comment: @Andy. Glad it gave you the correct answer. Could you possibly mark this as the accepted answer.